# How to avoid QGIS line width scaling when exporting geometry to KML?

Tags: qgis, kml

I have shapefiles loaded as linear geometries in QGIS.  I use the layer properties dialog to apply some styling to them (color + linewidth).  The goal is to output each layer as KML file.  My problem is, any geometry linewidth (pixels) I enter in QGIS ends up scaled by about 2.83 factor in KML.  For example, to get a 4.0 pixels KML linewidth, I have to enter 1.4111 as width value in QGIS.

What is this related to? Misuse of my own or software bug?